# Sum values of duplicate(common) keys in a list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to get the sum of duplicated key values in list

```
tax = [{'taxType': 'T1', 'amount': 140},{'taxType': 'T1', 'amount': 10}]
```

Expected result

```
tax = [{'taxType': 'T1', 'amount': 150}]
```

If `T1` is the same key and `150` is the result of sum amount values

Comment: no i edited to tax = [{'taxType': 'T1', 'amount': 140},{'taxType': 'T1', 'amount': 10}]

aggregated_data = {}

for dictionary in tax:
    key = (dictionary['taxType'], dictionary['amount'])
    aggregated_data[key] = aggregated_data.get(key, 0) 

data = [{'taxType': key[0], 'amount': key[1]} for key, value in aggregated_data.items()]

print(data) put i got the same list no change

Comment: in which part of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on @python_user's comment

Here is how you implement the solution for your code

```
tax = [{'taxType': 'T1', 'amount': 140},{'taxType': 'T1', 'amount': 10}]

aggregated_data = {}

for dictionary in tax:
    key = (dictionary['taxType'])
   
    aggregated_data[key] = aggregated_data.get(key, 0) + dictionary['amount']
    
tax = [{'taxType': key, 'amount': value} for key, value in aggregated_data.items()]

print(tax)
```

output

```
[{'taxType': 'T1', 'amount': 150}]
```

Comment: No need for `tax = [{'taxType': key, 'amount... ` to be in the for loop.

Comment: @DarrylG you are right, I have edited the code.